# JQuery search in array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

Lets say I have this html :

```
<ul>
<li class="cls">one</li>
<li class="cls active">tow</li>
<li class="cls">here</li>
<li class="cls">after</li>
</ul>
```

I'm selecting all `.cls` by this jquery selector : `$('.cls')` and put them in a variable:

```
var c=$('.cls');
```

`c` is an array of object now. I want to select `.active` item in this array by jQuery methods.
I do know i can use `$('.cls.active')` but this is not what I'm lookin for. I want to use `c`.
Is there any solution ?

note: `c.find('.active')` not working, because [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) searching in childs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

find:

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

filter:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or
>   pass the function's test.

```
c.filter('.active')
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `filter()` method of the jQuery object:

```
var active = c.filter('.active');
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aZUWg/).

Reference:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
c.filter('.active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .filter()

c.filter('.active');